# How can I translate this to english

Tags: anglais

année universitaire

mémoire de projet de fin d'etude
présenté pour obtenir diplome nationale d'ingenieur

spécialité : génie civile
Soutenu le --/--/-- ; devant le jury d’examen :
Président
Membre
 Encadrent
Invité

Comment: Did you have a try with it ?